# Chrome not showing "add to homescreen" in my PWA

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firebase, vue.js, progressive-web-apps

I followed Google's [first PWA tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/) and created my own project https://my-pwa-77d8a.firebaseapp.com. Everything looks fine:

- The project has a `manifest.json` file
- I'm using HTTPS on Firebase
- The code has the `<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">` tag
- My [manifest.json](https://my-pwa-77d8a.firebaseapp.com/manifest.json) file contains: icons specs, name, short_name, start_url
- I'm using Vue.js as my main framework and all the rest was built with vanilla JS
- The [service worker](https://my-pwa-77d8a.firebaseapp.com/worker.js) is set and running without errors
- The console shows no erros

[image: Manifest]
[image: Service Worker]

**manifest.json**

```
  {
    "short_name": "PizzaApp",
    "name": "My delicious PWA",
    "icons": [
      {
        "src": "img/launcher-icon-2x.png",
        "sizes": "96x96",
        "type": "image/png"
      },
      {
        "src": "img/launcher-icon-3x.png",
        "sizes": "144x144",
        "type": "image/png"
      },
      {
        "src": "img/launcher-icon-4x.png",
        "sizes": "192x192",
        "type": "image/png"
      }
    ],
    "start_url": "/index.html",
    "display": "standalone",
    "orientation": "portrait"
  }
```

I can manually add to homescreen both from mobile and desktop. But Chrome never shows the *add to homescreen* banner. What is wrong?

**SOLVED**

As pointed bellow, my service worker was trying to cache a missing `offline.html` file. I created the file, cleared the phone's cache and everything worked fine.

Comment: I don't know if it can be the problem, but https://my-pwa-77d8a.firebaseapp.com/offline.html is returning 404.

Comment: I've solved the `offline.html` issue, but it still not showing the banner.

Comment: It worked! I've created the `offline.html`, cleared my phone's cache then the browser showed the banner. Post your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I have this problem! I have the site served in https, I have a manifest.json and I have a service-worker being instantiated (it empty but that shouldn't be the problem) but it fails to prompt users to add to the homescreen. If I go to the browser settings in my phone and add it to homescreen it works but it doesn't prompt the users? Anyone has any clue? I have no errors at all...What could it be?

Comment: @Antonio yes.... happened probably after some update...even my pwa doesn't give notification anymore...

Comment: @ZeeshanHyder Thank you for your feedback. Please let me know if you come across a solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `offline.html` file (https://my-pwa-77d8a.firebaseapp.com/offline.html) is returning 404.

Comment: Yes, indeed! My worker was trying to cache a missing file. I've created the `offline.html`, cleared my phone's cache and everything worked perfectly! Thanks.